# Java 8 time zone ZoneRulesException: Unknown time-zone ID: EST

Tags: java, timezone

"EST" is one of the timeZone id from TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();

but

```
TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();  // contains EST
ZoneId.of("EST")
```

java.time.zone.ZoneRulesException: Unknown time-zone ID: EST

Comment: If you want to get the available IDs you can use with ZoneId, use `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`. Not `TimeZone.getAvailableIds()`.

Comment: `TimeZone` is not the same as `ZoneId`.... documentation: "*The default set of data is supplied by the IANA Time Zone Database (TZDB). This has region IDs of the form '{area}/{city}', such as 'Europe/Paris' or 'America/New_York'.*" also have a look at [SHORT_IDS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html#SHORT_IDS)

Comment: `TimeZone` is the legacy class now replaced by `ZoneId` and `ZoneOffset`. Never use the legacy date-time classes, use only *java.time* classes.

Comment: If there’s any way you can avoid it, don’t rely on three letter time zone abbreviations. EST, for example, may mean Australian Eastern Standard Time or North American Eastern Standard Time. On top comes the ambiguity whether it always means standard time, or it may mean standard or daylight time depending on circumstances.

Comment: ZoneId should just accept EST in the first place

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are mixing old and new API's.

[`TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getAvailableIDs--) returns Time Zone ID's that [`TimeZone.getTimeZone(String ID)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone-java.lang.String-) can resolve.

[`ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#getAvailableZoneIds--) returns Zone ID's that [`ZoneId.of(String zoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#of-java.lang.String-) can resolve.

If you compare the results of the 2, you will see:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> timeZones = Set.of(TimeZone.getAvailableIDs());
    Set<String> zoneIds = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds();
    System.out.println("Extra TimeZone's: " + diff(timeZones, zoneIds));
    System.out.println("Extra ZoneId's: " + diff(zoneIds, timeZones));
}
static Set<String> diff(Set<String> a, Set<String> b) {
    Set<String> diff = new TreeSet<>(a);
    diff.removeAll(b);
    return diff;
}
```

*Output (jdk-11.0.1)*

```
Extra TimeZone's: [ACT, AET, AGT, ART, AST, BET, BST, CAT, CNT, CST, CTT, EAT, ECT, EST, HST, IET, IST, JST, MIT, MST, NET, NST, PLT, PNT, PRT, PST, SST, VST]
Extra ZoneId's: []
```

As you can see, `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()` does not claim to support `EST`, only `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()` does.

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
ZoneId.of("EST", ZoneId.SHORT_IDS);
```

Explanation: ZoneID.SHORT_IDS maps deprecated 3-letter codes to regular ones and for some reason it must be specified explicitely to take effect.

From JDK javadoc: "Use of short zone IDs has been deprecated in TimeZone".

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer by editing it

Answer (score 13):

From [the Javadoc of `TimeZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html):

> **Three-letter time zone IDs**
>
> For compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some other three-letter time zone IDs (such as "PST", "CTT", "AST") are also supported. However, their use is deprecated because the same abbreviation is often used for multiple time zones (for example, "CST" could be U.S. "Central Standard Time" and "China Standard Time"), and the Java platform can then only recognize one of them.

`ZoneId` is different from `TimeZone`, and removes these problematic time zones.

Use `America/New_York` instead, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Problem is that [`ZoneId.SHORT_IDS.get("EST")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#SHORT_IDS) returns `-05:00`, not `America/New_York`, so it is not DST-aware. Javadoc even says it returns `-05:00`.